# Tagging equations with three \ast

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I want to tag some equations with `\ast`, for `\ast` and `\ast \ast` it's good, but for the third I would like to have the three `\ast` placed like in a triangle, so two `\ast` at the bottom and the third in the middle about above the base two.

```
$$\tag{$\ast$} \label{eq-1}$$
$$\tag{$\ast \ast$} \label{eq-2}$$
$$\tag{$\threeast$} \label{eq-3}$$
```

because `$\ast\ast\ast$` is too long

Comment: Just as a note, you shouldn't use `$$ x $$` use `\[ x \]` instead.

Comment: I use \begin{equation*}, \begin{align*}, \begin{multline} dependening on the situation, I just put $$ to make the code sample short

Comment: You shouldn't actually write $\ast\ast\ast$ or $***$ anyway, because TeX interprets the middle one as being an operator and adds spaces.  Write $\ast{\ast}\ast$ or $*{*}*$ instead to hide its operator-ness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my attempt. It's not ideal. And it borrows from Ian Thompson's answer in its use of the two commands, one for the symbol, one to protect it. It is more compact that Ian's and uses `\shortstack` rather than `tabular`. EDIT: I've changed the adjustments to be in `ex` rather than `pt` on egreg's suggestion. I've also got rid of the `\ensuremath{\displaystyle…` stuff I had before which I thought I needed...

```
\newcommand\iiiastsym{\raisebox{-.5ex}{\shortstack{%
  \(\ast\)\\[-.5ex]%
  \(\ast\ast\)}}%
}
\newcommand\iiiast{\protect\iiiastsym}
```

[image: three asts as a triangle]

By way of comparison, here are the proposed solutions:

[image]

Warning: `egreg`'s solution has been changed as compared to the way he gave it in order for it to display. Namely, I've put it inside `\(` and `\)` for mathmode and I've removed a `#` which is needed because the doubled `##` is for use inside a `\newcommand`...

Comment: Why `\ensuremath` in the argument of `\shortstack`?

Comment: So I can write \tag{$\iiiast$} or \tag{\iiiast} maybe?

Comment: I accepted your solution, it looks the best because the \ast's are not above/bewow the parethesis

Comment: @egreg I guessed it would be slightly more robust than explicitly going into mathmode. Is there a reason I shouldn't use `\ensuremath`?

Comment: @JohannesL in fairness, all of the solutions can be made to fit inside the parentheses with suitable `\raisebox` adjustments and the like...

Comment: `$\ast$` is as robust and more efficient; you *know* that items in `\shortstack` are typeset in text mode. Also the `\displaystyle` serves no purpose. There's no point in "robusting" what's inside `\shortstack`, which is fragile. Moreover, dimensions should be specified in terms of `ex`, so they will adapt to font size changes.

Comment: There is in fact the unicode symbol ⁂. I wonder if this works…

Comment: Spectacular code as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just to participate to the contest, here is a "primitive" solution:

```
\newcommand{\threeast}{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip\halign{##\cr
    \hfil$*$\hfil\cr$*\mkern4mu*$\cr}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be some limitations on what can go in the argument of a `\tag` command, which makes this awkward. Nevertheless...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\threeastsym{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} $\displaystyle\ast$ \\[-5pt] 
                                             $\displaystyle \ast\ast$ \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\threeast{\protect\threeastsym}
\begin{document}
\[ \tag{$\ast$} \label{eq-1} \]
\[ \tag{$\ast \ast$} \label{eq-2} \]
\[ \label{eq-3} \tag{\threeast} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following definition of `\threeast` (which requires the use of the `amsmath` package):

```
\newcommand{\threeast}{\ensuremath{\overset{\textstyle\ast}{\ast\ast}}}
```

You may wish to lower the entire construct by a couple of points in order to improve its vertical positioning.

Comment: overset requires `amsmath`. It's worth making that clear...